# TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_mode'

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, reddit, praw

Below is the code that I use for a telegram bot that posts new updates from my preferred subreddit. This is not my code (I found it online on stack overflow) but I keep getting this error. I've searched everywhere but there wasn't any solution I could find. Anyway here it is, even slight information of which direction should I go would be greatly appreciated.

```
import telebot
import praw
import config
bot_token = 'x'
bot_chatID = '@monsterKing_bot'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='x', \
                     client_secret='x', \
                     user_agent='x', \
                     username='x ', \
                     password='x')

def reddit_scraper(submission):
    news_data = []
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('coronavirus')
    new_subreddit = subreddit.new(limit=500)
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=5):
        data = {}
        data['title'] = submission.title
        data['link'] = submission.url
        news_data.append(data)
    return news_data

def get_msg(news_data):
    msg = '\n\n\n'
    for news_item in news_data:
        title = news_item['title']
        link = news_item['link']
        msg += title+'\n[<a href="'+link+'">Read the full article --></a>]'
        msg += '\n\n'

    return msg

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('coronavirus')
new_subreddit = subreddit.new(limit=500)
for submission in subreddit.new(limit=1):
    news_data = reddit_scraper(submission)
    if len(news_data) > 0:
        msg = get_msg(news_data)
        status = bot.send_message(chat_id='@monsterKing_bot', text=msg, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)        
        if status:            
            print(status)
else:
    print('No updates.')
```

Full error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mayan\Downloads\redditscraperbot.py", line 42, in <module>
    status = bot.send_message(chat_id='@monsterKing_bot', text=msg, parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_mode'
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `parse_mode` argument?

Comment: ```{'ok': False, 'error': 'Got unexpected response. (404) - {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}'}
No updates.```

Comment: Got the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752391/python-telebot-got-unexpected-response

but now it says this:

```{'ok': False, 'error': 'Got unexpected response. (400) - {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}'}
No updates.```

Comment: Something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174831/telegram-bot-chat-not-found
I sent a message to my own bot on telegram but it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 6):

try pip install pyTelegramBotAPI instead of pip install telebot

Answer (score 0):

My chat id was wrong. Chat id is a number we can get from another bot (userinfobot)

`chat_id= 1261748gd278` not `chat_id=@name`...